# Per-Route authentication is causing RouteExecutionEarlyExitException

Tags: c#, authentication, nancy

I'm quite new to Nancy and am now experimenting with Auth. Looking forward to fully implement Forms authentication.

For testing purposes, I have 3 modules set up.

**Other module:**

```
public class OtherModule : NancyModule
{
    public OtherModule() : base()
    {
        // Use global, module level authentication.
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        Get["/other"] = _ =>
        {
            return "Other";
        };

        Get["/woot"] = _ =>
        {
            return "Woot";
        };
    }
}
```

**Main module:**

```
public class MainModule : NancyModule
{
    public MainModule() : base()
    {
        Get["/yolo"] = _ =>
        {
            // Use per-route authentication.
            this.RequiresAuthentication();

            return "#YOLO";
        };
    }
}
```

**AuthModule:**

```
public class AuthModule : NancyModule
{
    public AuthModule() : base()
    {
        Get["/login"] = _ =>
        {
            return "To proceed, you must authenticate. [show form]";
        };
    }
}
```

Now, when I navigate to `/other` and/or `/woot`, I am redirected to `/login` - as expected.  Though, when I navigate to `/yolo`, the application throws an `Nancy.ErrorHandling.RouteExecutionEarlyExitException`, where I assumed it should redirect me to `/login?returnUrl=seeme`.

I have walked through [the github forms auth source](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/tree/34d88eb387d152e93b37600fe937900a278c88bd/src/Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Forms), which features the behavior in [this file](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/34d88eb387d152e93b37600fe937900a278c88bd/src/Nancy.Demo.Authentication.Forms/PartlySecureModule.cs). I cannot seem to find any major differences (my [Bootstrapper](http://pastebin.com/cRHwMQVw), my [IUserMapper](http://pastebin.com/e3UjFYfA), my [IUserIdentity](http://pastebin.com/e9Yqy1AY)).

Is my use wrong here? Should I try/catch it and prepare responses accordingly? Is it a bug?

I'm running NancyFX in a self-hosted environment (`Nancy.Hosting.Self`), no ASP and no OWIN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

False alert, false alert.

It was my Visual Studio debugger, who just reported about the exception.

Of course, as usual, I pushed "Break" and the app went down. Pressing "Continue" instead, did redirect me to the correct page.

Comment: You can also open Visual Studio Exception settings and hit "Add...", choose "Common Language Runtime" and type "Nancy.ErrorHandling.RouteExecutionEarlyExitException". Then you must uncheck the two checkboxes. Visual Studio will ignore this exception from now on.